# registration form php only refresh phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I created a registration.php a login user.php an error.php and a server.php which errors validate and server connects my php form to database. login.php is working as is saying wrong id and/or password while registration form not working. When I click submit its just like refreshing and nothing its saved to database. Trying 3 days and can't figure why. maybe its my p.c problem? I'm working with XAMPP and phpmyadmin and dreamweaver.

here is my register.php.

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forms.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h2>Register</h2>
</div>

<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_1">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Confirm Paswword:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_2">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Student ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="studentid">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Course:</label>
        <input type="text" name="course">
    </div>  
    <div class="input-group">
        <center><button type="submit" name="register" class="btn">Register</button></center>
    </div>
    <p>
        Already a registered student? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my server.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // variable declaration
    $name = "";
    $surname = "";
    $email = "";
    $studentid = "";
    $password_1 ="";
    $password_2 = "";
    $course = "";
    $errors = array();
    $_SESSION['success'] = "";

    // connect to database
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

    // if register button clicked receive all inputs from the form
    if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['surname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['studentid']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_1 = md5($password_1);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
    $password_2 = md5($password_2);
    $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['course']);


    // ensure that form fields are filled properly
    if (empty($name)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Name is required"); 
                      }
    if (empty($surname)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Surame is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($email)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Email is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($studentid)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Student ID is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($password_1)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Password is required"); 
    }
    if (empty($course)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Course is required"); 
    }

    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }   

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1); //encrypt the password before saving in the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email, studentid, password, course) 
              VALUES(0,'$name','$surname', '$email', '$studentid' '$password', '$course')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['studentid'] = $studentid;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
  }

}

// login user
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['studentid']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($studentid)) {
    array_push($errors, "Student ID is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE studentid='$studentid' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['studentid'] = $studentid;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong Student ID or Password. Please try again.");
    }
  }
}

?>
```

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pfrA.png)

Comment: your form action is pointing to register.php and you are saying "and this is my server.php" . Can you check

Comment: Do you have `register.php` ?

Comment: _Note:_ You're not working with PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyAdmin is simply a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases.

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: You're also not saving your `$errors`-array anywhere.

Comment: You should also never escape passwords before hashing them. Since you're only saving the hash, you already know that it will be safe to use. If you want to properly secure your script from SQL Injecitons, you should look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has some security issues in certain situations.

Comment: Hello guys and thanks for answering. 1. yes the first is the register.php. 2. oki i will remove hash and thanks for help. 3. err do i need to save errors? :$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you button name is different from the one in php

```
//previous code button clicked for register
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {}
```

instead of

```
//button clicked for register
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {}
```

and also your query
if your "id" an auto increment, leave it blank rather put 0, you can also do as follow

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, email, studentid, password, 
course)VALUES('$name','$surname', '$email', '$studentid' '$password', '$course')";
```

**UPDATED TO HELP ANYONE WITH SIMILAR ISSUE**

For anyone that may have similar code challenge, please check if every semi column, comma and dot are where they should be.

You can debug also by echoing out the values to know where the problem is probably coming from.

Also read through the comments you might pick up what you need from there.
Hope this helped.

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering. yes its finally working and validate but not saving in the database and when trying to log in with the id and password i set in register is not logging in saying wrong id and/or password.. hm.. i need to figure why isn't saving it.. Also yea its auto increment and removed it than kyou

Comment: actually when i register is logging in and when i log out and try to login again can't find the ''username'' ( studentid) and/or password maybe beacuse its not saved on database.

Comment: @Onix md5 isn't the best of best for password hashing, read more on php password_hash(), also, probably your data isn't in the database, also you sometimes it isn't the best way to compare two hashes via mysql you can call the other hash out and compare using normal php if statement

Comment: Thank you i remove the md5's and i will read more. hmm i have the databases called register and tabled called users.. maybe i have to delete the id? once i remove it from $query.

Comment: Before I go further in answering, I will love to know if you have checked to see if the data is in the database table users, Lets start from there, am willing to offer more support if you need it

Comment: thank you very much for your offering. yes i checked and there is no data i can upload a screenshot if you need

Comment: Okay feel free to do so

Comment: i upload it at the end of the post named 'database' you can click on that. thank you

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, email, studentid, password,course) VALUES('$name','$surname', '$email', '$studentid' '$password', '$course')";  1) please verify this is exactly how it looks in your query kindly take note of spacing, 2) Debug the page by commenting the header() and echoing out each of the values to ensure they are not empty. 3) please verify that you have change the isset($_POST['reg_user']) to isset($_POST['register']).

Comment: Lastly if you verify all of this and they are okay, let me know, I will write a similar query for you, but using the mysqli object oriented method

Comment: omg i appriciate you save my life thank you veru much . .was a comma forgot a comma beetween studentid and course... lot of thanks and have a niceday ;) now need to finish admin log in and done!

Comment: You are. welcome,I wish you the best of luck. Am glad this helped to answer/solve the problem

Comment: one last thing when i register the data saved on the database but it generates an auto password to log in.. i use for example password and id '12345' and in database everythign is 12345 expect password is '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed05' jsut asking if you know.
thank you.

Comment: you expect the password to be hashes and not plain text? or you want plain text and not hashes?

Comment: yea yea yea just fix it before i see ur answer found it thx. neede to change $password to $password_1 now need to make it register more than once cuz it only instert 1 row 1 registration. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your Query You take `surname` instead of `username`.
Change Query 
From this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, email, studentid, password, course) 
              VALUES(0,'$name','$surname', '$email', '$studentid' '$password', '$course')";
```

To this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email, studentid, password, course) 
              VALUES('$name','$username', '$email', '$studentid' '$password', '$course')";
```

And there are lots of spelling mistake in code. kindly fill relax and check all spelling.

Comment: I would recommend removing the `id`-column from the query all together.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time and help. i know there are msitakes and i will fix it i just want to make this work first and then relax and correcting mistakes and spellings. thank you for your help